# Is it unsafe to use local variables in a call to begininvoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

I have to take over the source code of a bigger application from my colleaque that is written in C#. It uses windows forms an threads and right now it works as it should. 
But one thing I am not sure about, is the way he handled parameters that are used in delegates that are raised from the thread to the windows forms in the application. I don't know why, but he defined many different object arrays with varying number of elements, eg:

```
private object[] delegateArray1;
private object[] delegateArray3;
private object[] delegateArray3A;
```

and in the code he used it then

```
delegateArray1 = new object[1]; // in the constructor of the thread class 
delegateArray3 = new object[3]; 
delegateArray3a = new object[3];

// and this somewhere in the thread loop
delegateArray3[0] = systemtests.FehlerText;
delegateArray3A[1] = CheckState.Unchecked;
delegateArray3A[2] = testKanal;
sender.BeginInvoke(merkerInfoDelegate, delegateArray3);
```

whereby `sender` is the containercontrol from which the thread has been created.
`merkerInfoDelegate` points to a method with the signature

```
public void InfoAnzeige(string scrollText, CheckState state, int kanal);
```

The first question that I have:

Is it possible that my variables / objects that I pass to the BeginInvoke method are being garbage collected and thus are invalid when the delegate method gets finally executed. When yes, how do I prevent this from happen?

Is it not possible to call the delegate like this:

```
sender.BeginInvoke(merkerInfoDelegate, systemtests.FehlerText, CheckState.Unchecked, testKanal);
```

I would like to make the code more readable, more safe and more reliable. I think of declaring classes like the class MouseEventArgs, that consist of these parameters and that encapsulate all necessary data to be passed to the delegate method in the windows forms class...

```
public InfoDelegateEventArgs
{
    public String Fehlertext;
    public CheckState state;
    public int Kanal;
}
```

this could be used like this:

```
idea = new InfoDelegateEventArgs(){...};
sender.BeginInvoke(merkerInfoDelegate, idea);
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to pass CheckState instead of just a bool?

Comment: Your variables are not garbage-collected - they're still being referenced as you call `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: You can just do `sender.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => InfoAnzeige(systemtests.FehlerText, CheckState.Unchecked, testKanal))` to avoid all this clutter.

Comment: @Botonomous: I don't think so, but the number and type of arguments are solely for explanation :-)

Comment: @xxbbcc: at the time `BeginInvoke` is being called, they hopefully are still referenced. But are they when the target method is being executed hours or days later? I mean, If i leave the method in which `BeginInvoke` is being called the local variables on the stack will be lost...

Comment: @WolfgangRoth Value types are passed by value and reference types don't live on the stack.

Comment: @Evk Will this work, if I get the method `InfoAnzeige` passed in the thread class constructor? One time, `InfoAnzeige` will be from class `FormA` and the next time it will be from class `FormB`, so it could be passed like `frmA.InfoAnzeige` and `frmB.InfoAnzeige` ...

Comment: Yes it will work for instance members too (`frmA.XXX`). As for garbage collection - you should not worry about that in this case.

Comment: He did not know how a params array argument works.  Well, that's fairly sad, but it is neither wrong nor unsafe.

Comment: @HansPassant, could it be that there are memory leak issues when using delegates and begininvoke, endinvoke?

Comment: No, that could not be.  Trying to come up with theories for a problem you did not document is surely the worst possible way to ask a question.

Comment: I dont think, that the memory leaks are an issue right now - he just mentioned them, and IIRC he mentioned the delegate parameter arrays in the same discussion :-). And all this was years ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is safe to pass "local" variables but remember they are no longer "local" once you pass them. The references have now been passed off to another operation that may be running concurrently on a separate thread. Now multiple threads have access to the "local" variable and thus it might require locking or other thread-safe treatment.

You don't need to worry about it being GC'd because there is still a reference that was passed to `BeginInvoke`.

Comment: Value type variables are no problem i think, but reference type values are?

Comment: @WolfgangRoth yes, the OP is passing arrays, which are references.